# Is it practical to normalize timestamps in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have click data on a server that expects more than one click per second, is it practical to normalize timestamps?

Basically, this:

```
CREATE TABLE clicks(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
timestamp TIMESTAMP NULL
)
```

VS

```
CREATE TABLE clicks(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
timestamp_id INT(6) UNSIGNED NULL
)
CREATE TABLE timestamps(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
timestamp TIMESTAMP  NULL
)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?!

Comment: Seems like a waste of space to me, using one unique integer to represent another unique integer.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Only time you split stuff out into another table is if there is another piece of data associated with it you want to save by itself. Not the case here, and the timestamp is not going to get reused.